# A little brain fart

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a nicer, less *immature* saying?

I love using 'A Freudian slip', but that is only applicable in certain situations.

Comment: I sometimes say a "***thinko***".

Comment: I don't think a Freudian slip is the same. I brain fart is when you forget something that you normally would know, such as someone's name. A Freudian slip is when you say the wrong thing, inadvertently revealing some subconscious thought. It is also used to refer to any accidental use of a sexual term in an inappropriate context.

Comment: A Freudian slip is when you say one thing, but mean your mother.

Comment: I call it a brain burp.

Comment: "Brain flatus" would be a little more formal. ;-)

Comment: Only a moment ago I had an answer to suggest, but *it seems to have escaped me*. ;)

Comment: AFAIK a brain fart is not "just any lapse/oversight", a brain fart is when for some usually unknown reason you go off the rail into a direction which makes no sense at all, and which in normal conditions you totally wouldn't do.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You mean "cephalus flatulus" ...

Comment: A Freudian slip is a small error in speach that reveals something the speaker is thinking and is trying to hide.  It doesn't necessarily have a sexual content.

Comment: I like using "**brain cramp**". It is easy to remember because it rolls off the tongue like "brain fart", but not nearly so rudely.

Comment: @SrJoven What? Why your mother? :P

Comment: @HelloGoodbye "A Freudian slip is when you say one thing, but mean another" - It's a nice play on words. In this case another rhymes with mother, which ties into Freuds theory Oedipal complex for which he is famed for.

Comment: The notion that phrases like "brain fart" are "immature" is confused. It is actually the hyper-emotional responses to such words that are immature. But if you're looking for more "professional" language, just say "Sorry, I wasn't thinking clearly".

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In formal contexts, you might consider a temporary "***lapse***", or, more specifically, a "***mental lapse***".

In less formal situations, I've often used "***thinko***"; sometimes elderly people say they've had a "***senior moment***".

If you've specifically overlooked something otherwise obvious, then a short, descriptive term is a (minor) "***oversight***".

Comment: Duplicated one of your offerings based on failure to read, so deleted. Links to sources would be good.

Comment: A momentary lapse of reason, if you're a Pink Floyd fan.

Comment: I like a mental lapse and the pink floyd reference per @hobbs, im going to use both. Thanks

Comment: perfect answers from Dan

Comment: I think 'senior moment' gets used somewhat ironically by less-than-elderly people at times, too.

Answer (score 38):

[Mental hiccup](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mental+hiccup&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmental%20hiccup%3B%2Cc0) is a fairly common idiom which can be used in circles where "brain fart" might raise eyebrows.

I would not, however, equate it with a "Freudian slip" which implies an inadvertent exposing of someone's subconscious/secret thoughts or desires.

Comment: another great answer

Answer (score 8):

There is also "**mental block**" or "**neuron misfiring**" (not commonly used but I like it).

Comment: You get some alliterative appeal by combining these, and I've heard it used before:  "mental misfire"

Comment: We could also say a "miswired neuron", which sounds a little like ["getting ones wires crossed"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_one%27s_wires_crossed), although that is a more specific situation.

Answer (score 7):

My favorite is from an Encyclopedia Brown book that I read 30+ years ago:

Bubbles in the Think-Tank.

I sometimes refer to others (or even myself) as suffering from cranial-rectal inversion, but I feel that implies a longer term than the momentary lapse implied of a brain fart or bubbles in the think-tank.

Comment: Despite the superficial technicality of the words, I find "cranial-rectal inversion" to be substantially *more* immature than "brain fart". Certainly more graphic, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I've used "synapse lapse" before. It is informal but more refined than a fart.

Comment: I like the awkward rhyme.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly more offensive than brain fart, **a senior moment** or **a blonde moment**

Comment: -1 OP asked for "_What is a nicer, less immature saying?_" not "_more offensive_"

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think that "senior moment" is very offensive.

Comment: I think it's offensive to seniors.

Comment: @joeytwiddle only if they understand it.

Comment: Whether or not it's offensive really depends on context. Judge your company and if they're offended, don't use the term again.

Comment: I think both these terms can only be used in a self-deprecating way. I have a blonde friend who is highly intelligent but who will claim "blonde moments" when she makes a mistake; similarly, a 60's scientist who forgets a name and blames a "senior moment" is recognizing that the typical effects of aging are affecting his brain. Don't ever use it on others - "wow you had a real blonde moment there" - unless you know them very, very well.

Comment: It can be mature AND offensive !

Comment: Duh!  I can't believe nobody thought of blonde moment!  (I had a blonde moment, I guess.)  Yes, BTW of course it is offensive, it's ridiculous to suggest it's not.

Comment: "It can be mature AND offensive" -- Apparently a brain fart led you to offer this strawman while failing to recognize that it is not consistent with "nicer [AND] less immature".

Answer (score 2):

I've used "I just had a moment." and heard "Are you having a moment?" Short for senior moment I guess.

Comment: Generally 'having a moment' refers to someone having a tantrum or otherwise being unsuitable for the company of others, no?

Comment: That would be 'having a fit' @atroon. Upon being berated for obvious incorrectness I'd say, "Sorry, I just had a moment there."

Answer (score 0):

A **mental aberration** is something I've used before. It even features in [ODO's dictionary entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aberration):

> **aberration**
>
> A departure from what is normal, usual, or expected, typically an unwelcome one:
> *I see these activities as some kind of mental aberration*

Comment: To me, that phrase would imply something actually _pathological_ about the workings of the brain in question.

Comment: This sounds slightly too extreme while also too general; it could be applied to believing a logical inconsistency. It isn't directly wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're squeamish about saying fart, try the word 'mistake'.

Comment: "What's that smell?" "Oh sorry, I just mistook."

Comment: @RyanJ I feel we must now endeavour to put that phrase into common usage.

Comment: Those of us who mistake of mistake prefer the term "fluffy."

Answer (score 0):

How about *having a blind spot*?